# How can I play an mp3 clientside by getting it from the server?

Tags: javascript, audio, express, server, mp3

The client sends a GET request to the server with the name of the audio file it wants. The server, which has access to the audio files, constructs a path to the mp3.

Right now I am calling `result.sendFile('/audio/mysong.mp3')` on the server, and getting the binary data on the client.

I haven't found a way to construct the mp3 object on the client to where I can just create a new Audio object and call `.play()`. Is there any way to do this?

Is there a better way to send the mp3 to the client?

Thanks